# Hidden state in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is what I have so far:

[image: example]

This is simple drop down based login. 
What I want to do is to change the login bar to something else when person logs in, but I want current state to be unchanged.

(in this example I'd like the "This is home view" text to be displayed regardless of login state).

My current code structure:

```
<body  ng-app="pmfApp">
<div>
    <!---  login form and stuff.... ---->
</div>

<nav class="navbar">
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div id="status-buttons" class="text-center">
            <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="home">Home</a>
            <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="about"> About</a>
      </div>
</div>
</nav>

<div ui-view>
    <!--- I have home state view triggered ---->
</div>
```

So if login goes successful I have something like this:

```
    $auth.login(credentials).then(function(data) {
            $state.go('???????', {});
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to set a flag in the `$scope` to track if the user is logged in.  You could then use this with `ng-if` to show and hide the sections you want based on the users login status.

```
<div ng-if="!loggedInFlag">
    <!---  login form and stuff.... ---->
</div>

<nav class="navbar" ng-if="loggedInFlag">
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div id="status-buttons" class="text-center">
            <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="home">Home</a>
            <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="about"> About</a>
      </div>
</div>
</nav>

<div ui-view>
    <!--- I have home state view triggered ---->
</div>
```